# In Github actions get Shell stdout and post it in a PR Comment

Tags: shell, github-actions

Im making a CI/CD pipeline and I'm trying to get the shell script output and post it in a PR comment and below is what I have so far.

I can see the shell script output when the pipeline runs but I struggling to save the output and post it in a PR comment.

```
      - name: run sh command
        id: sh
        run: bash ./update/commands.sh | tee output.txt
      - name: Get coverage output
        id: get_coverage
        run: echo "::set-output name=coverage < output.txt)"
      - uses: mshick/add-pr-comment@v1
        with:
          message: |
            Coverage found ${{steps.get_coverage.outputs.coverage}}
            
            !
          repo-token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          repo-token-user-login: 'github-actions[bot]' # The user.login for temporary GitHub tokens
          allow-repeats: false # This is the default
```

Comment: See [Setting an output parameter](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#setting-an-output-parameter).

Answer (score 1):

I'd personally rely on the github cli from which it's very easy to add a comment to a PR:

```
gh pr comment 1234 --body-file file.txt
```

In this case I would redirect the output of the coverage to  a file and then pass the path to that file to `gh pr comment`.

make sure you declare:

```
permissions:
  issues: write
```

In the workflow file to ensure the workflow can add comments to the issue.